# What is the smallest value $tr(A)$ can take if $tr(A^2) = 241$? ($tr(A)$ is the trace of the matrix $A$)

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, matrix-calculus

I'm working on a problem involving a 2 × 2 matrix $A$ with different eigenvalues and a
determinant $det(A) = 60$. Given that $tr(A^2) = 241$, I'm tasked with finding the smallest
possible value for $tr(A)$.
I've tried utilizing the relationship between the trace and determinant of a matrix with its
eigenvalues, expressing $tr(A)$ and $det(A)$ in terms of the eigenvalues ${\lambda}_{1}$ and ${\lambda}_{2}$. However, I
seem to be struggling to derive a conclusive relationship between $tr(A)$ and $det(A)$ that helps
me solve for the minimum value of $tr(A)$ satisfying the given condition.
Could someone provide guidance or a step-by-step approach to set up the equations necessary
to solve for the smallest possible value of $tr(A)$ given the conditions provided?

Comment: You need to minimise $\lambda+\frac{60}{\lambda}$ over $\mathbb R\setminus\{-\sqrt{60},\sqrt{60}\}$ subject to $\lambda^2+\frac{3600}{\lambda^2}=241$. This should not be difficult: the answer is given by $-\sqrt{a}$ where $a$ is the largest positive root of $x^2-241x+3600=0$.

Comment: To format your question, see [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Answer (score 5):

Express the given values in terms of the eigenvalues $\{a,b\}$
$$\eqalign{
\def\tr{\operatorname{tr}}
\det(A) &= ab\doteq 60,\qquad\tr(A^2) = a^2+b^2 \doteq 241 \\
}$$
Now expand the *square* of the trace
$$\eqalign{
\Big(\tr(A)\Big)^2 &= (a+b)^2 \\
 &= a^2+b^2+2ab \\
 &= 241+2(60) \\
 &= 361 \\
}$$
Therefore $\quad\tr(A) = \pm19$